# Mongoose showing error of a string repeatedly

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I am repeatedly getting this error in my server.js. Can anyone help me what to do?

the error:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` 
or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)      
    at C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
    at C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:379:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Priyansh\Desktop\WorkOut\backend\server.js:10:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
```

server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express =  require('express')
const WorkoutRoutes = require('./routes/workouts.js')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api/workouts', WorkoutRoutes)

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to database')
    // listen to port
    app.listen(4000, () => {
      console.log('listening for requests on port', 4000)
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

.env file

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://Priyansh:Priyansh123@workout.imrdamh.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

workouts.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.json({msg :"Getting a workout"})
})

router.post('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.json({msg :"Posting a workout"})
})

router.get('/:id',(req,res) =>{
    res.json({msg :"Getting a single workout"})
})

router.delete('/:id',(req,res) =>{
    res.json({msg :"Deleting a workout"})
})

router.patch('/:id',(req,res) =>{
    res.json({msg :"Updating a workout"})
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

could you print out (or log) the env. variable to see how the program fetches it? if the type is undefined, then the program must either not find it, or interpret it in a certain way (it's just how i usually debug, i have zero experience lol)

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read the guidelines, this is not an answer